# Error consuming .Net Web service in Oracle Fusion SOA

Tags: .net, web-services, soa, oracle-fusion-middleware

Our client has provided .Net 4.0 based Web service which we are trying to consume in Oracle Fusion SOA 12. .Net web method passes data in XML format. While consuming .Net Web service WSDL, Oracle Fusion SOA is breaking in several places.

One example of break is here:

```
><xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="Content" nillable="true" type="q35:ArrayOfstring" xmlns:q35="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/
```

One more example of break.

This web service is hosted by Amazon site.
http://ec2-50-19-218-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com/BuyDesign/ConfiguratorService/ConfiguratorWebService.svc?wsdl

While importing WSDL file, we are getting following error.

Exception: Invalid reference: 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TDCI.Configurator.ServiceContract:QueueStatus'

Please let me know any changes/settings required

Comment: XMLSpy says that this is a valid WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the reference exists, either in the supplied WSDL file or in a separate schema that your component is aware of. Perhaps the namespace `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TDCI.Configurator.ServiceContract:` refers to an external schema that must be available to your code?